# How to make the Telegram bot send the PDF file or return a G-drive link

Tags: python, python-3.x, bots, telegram, telegram-bot

I am just working around the Telegram bot using Python, and I wish to send a pdf file or a drive link via the bot. However, I am getting an error.

```
No error handlers are registered, logging exception.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/murgod/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/telegram/ext/dispatcher.py", line 557, in process_update
    handler.handle_update(update, self, check, context)
  File "/home/murgod/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/telegram/ext/handler.py", line 199, in handle_update
    return self.callback(update, context)
  File "/home/murgod/KubeBot/KubeBot-4/GKEbot.py", line 217, in send_resume
    bot.send_document(
  File "/home/murgod/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/telegram/bot.py", line 133, in decorator
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/murgod/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/telegram/bot.py", line 976, in send_document
    return self._message(  # type: ignore[return-value]
  File "/home/murgod/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/telegram/bot.py", line 339, in _message
    result = self._post(endpoint, data, timeout=timeout, api_kwargs=api_kwargs)
  File "/home/murgod/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/telegram/bot.py", line 298, in _post
    return self.request.post(
  File "/home/murgod/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/telegram/utils/request.py", line 361, in post
    result = self._request_wrapper(
  File "/home/murgod/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/telegram/utils/request.py", line 279, in _request_wrapper
    raise BadRequest(message)
telegram.error.BadRequest: Wrong file identifier/http url specified
```

The defined function is

```
def xyz(update, context):
   resume_url = ''  
   bot.send_document(
       chat_id=update.effective_chat.id,
       document=xyz_url,
       filename='xyz.pdf',          
   )

xyz_handler = CommandHandler('xyz', xyz)
dispatcher.add_handler(xyz_handler)
```

Does anyone have a suggestion?